# Constraints on Dijit DateTextBox [Valid days of the week]

Tags: javascript, constraints, widget, dojo

Quick question about the Dijit.Form.DateTextBox

http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/DateTextBox

This page contains the following: "also validates against developer-provided constraints like min, max, valid days of the week, etc."

I can't seem to find documentation allowing me to provide a constraint on the days of the week.  For instance, i need to have a DateTextBox which only allows users to choose a date that occurs on a Sunday.

I'd appreciate any help with this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked heavily into the source code for this, and I think the manual may be misleading you a bit - there's no way to do this using the object's constraints. The following quote from their user forums seems to back up my findings:

> DateTextBox doesn't let you customize
>   isDisabledDate at this time. It only
>   lets you set min/max. You would
>   probably have to patch or subclass
>   DateTextBox to provide your own
>   isDisabledDate implementation and
>   check during validation.

You can see an example of such a subclass of DateTextBox at http://dojotoolkit.org/forum/dijit-dijit-0-9/dijit-support/datetextbox-mondays-only-selectable#comment-19508.

If that's too much work for you, DateTextBox DOES descend from dijit.form.ValidationTextBox, so we can use this widget's regExpGen to create a validator - it won't prevent us from selecting invalid dates, but it will cause dijit to mark the widget as invalid and give the user a 'The value entered is not valid'.

```
dijit.byId('toDate').regExpGen = function() { 
  if (dojo.date.locale.format(this.value, {datePattern: "E", selector: "date"}) == 6)
    return ".*";
  return "0";
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get access to the Calendar object which the DateTextBox contains. We have managed to disable weekends when we have access to this directly.

Answer (score 2):

As it happens, the `isDisabledDate` function on the `Calendar` object inside a `DateTextBox` just calls `rangeCheck` on the `DateTextBox` itself. So, for your purposes, this will work:

```
dijit.byId('toDate').rangeCheck = function(date,constraints) {
  var day=date.getDay();
  return day===0;
}
```

You'd have to add the constraint logic back in if you ALSO wanted the min/max stuff, but this solves the problem as stated, and it's pretty short.

Answer (score 1):

A feature I hope to get to soon

http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/4765